# How to install kernel development headers to staging with Buildroot for kernel module development?

Tags: linux-kernel, make, buildroot

I am planning to do some Rasperry Pi C/C++ kernel module development using BuildRoot 2015.08.1.

What works:

- I can build a kernel and a rootfs and boot the Raspberry Pi.
- I can build/rebuild a "hello world" using the BuildRoot toolchain either as a generic-package or an autotools-package.

What does not work:

- I cannot include some kernel headers, for instance linux/module.h. The toolchain does not find this header file.

I had a look at output/staging/usr/include. I can find some linux headers, for instance linux/net.h. However others are not there, for instance linux/module.h.

The header I am looking for is present in the kernel source tree. However it does not appear to be installed to staging. I am not 100% sure that BuildRoot called "make headers_install", but it seems like a reasonable assumption. Would anyone have any pointers to how "make headers_install" selects the headers to be installed? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: An userspace program doesn't need the kernel headers. They are reserved for kernel core/drivers.

Comment: @AlexandreBelloni: Fair comment. I am actually trying to develop a kernel module. I edited the question to mention this.

Comment: @AlexandreBelloni actually that's not true, kernel utilities (e.g. dmraid) requires some aspects of the kernel headers (e.g. scsi/sg.h), as a matter of fact glibc does parse a host of kernel headers and deploys them as they provide the user-space kernel-space interconnect.

Comment: And they are shipped by the libc, as you state so they are part of the toolchain provided by buildroot.

Answer (score 1):

---

> I cannot include some kernel headers, for instance linux/module.h. The
>   toolchain does not find this header file.

Kernel module : The 'make' command has "internals" to do that. Works (only) if you are using a special »*Kernel module Makefile*« → →

→ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33589276/linux-kernel-module-compilation/33589361#33589361

---

Comment: you should give a little more details, your answer is berdering a link-only answer.

Comment: It does solve my problem, thanks. Information about the internals would satisfy my curiosity and be very much appreciated.

Comment: It may work but this is probably using the headers from your host, not your target.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fully automated out-of-tree setup for kernel modules: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/b89ba9b799480e4eb1975f0a704409efb7d667d1/kernel_module/external.mk

I've described a minimal version of that at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307328/how-to-add-a-linux-kernel-driver-module-as-a-buildroot-package/43874273#43874273

The package type `$(eval $(kernel-module))` basically sets up everything for us.